# Convert a pandas dataframe in the form of a matrix into a table

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have a dataframe in the following form:

```
   P  Q  R  S
A  0  2  1  1
B  2  0  1  1
C  1  1  0  0
D  1  1  0  0
```

I want to change it into the following form:

```
A P 0
A Q 2
A R 1
A S 1
B P 2
B Q 0
B R 1
B S 1 and so on...
```

Basically, the fomat is:

```
Row Column Value
```

I'm looking to transform the data in this manner to be able to feed it into Cytoscape for plotting a graph.

Are there any in-built functions in pandas that I can use for this transformation?

Comment: can you add one more row / column? it's not clear how do you want to continue...

Comment: Updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['a','b','c']
print df
    a  b  c
0   A  P  0
1   A  Q  2
2   A  R  1
3   A  S  1
4   B  P  2
5   B  Q  0
6   B  R  1
7   B  S  1
8   C  P  1
9   C  Q  1
10  C  R  0
11  C  S  0
12  D  P  1
13  D  Q  1
14  D  R  0
15  D  S  0
```